# How do you feel about sharing Gardening.SE content on Pinterest?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**Update:** I've started pinning things to a Gardening board on the Stack Exchange Pinterest account. If you're on Pinterest (or if you're just curious what this is all about), check it out: http://pinterest.com/stackexchange/

[Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) is an online bulletin board of sorts - users pin images, write notes about what they love, and organize them into different "boards."

I am putting together a plan for a Stack Exchange Pinterest account, with the idea being that Stack Exchange as a brand can start participating in the broader conversations about topics we have sites for. Subjects that are popular on Pinterest and have a corresponding SE site are:

- Photography
- DIY/Home Improvement
- Gardening & Landscaping
- Food (corresponds to Seasoned Advice)
- Fitness & Nutrition (less popular on Pinterest than the other topics)

The goal of trying out a Stack Exchange Pinterest account is to meet potential new users in a place where they are already congregating. Pinterest has had explosive growth in the past six months, and its primary demographic is different enough from most Stack Exchange sites' current demographics for it to be worth a shot.

Each of the above topics would be its own board on the Stack Exchange Pinterest account. Content ("pins") would include content from our own sites as well as interesting content from elsewhere around the Internet.

**My question for you all is this:**

Are you in favor of, or against, having your Stack Exchange content pinned on Pinterest? My plan is to write user names in the pin description for any content that comes from this site, but Pinterest does not require attribution for content that is re-pinned (meaning that my attribution to the OP might be lost if other people repost that content).

Everything that I would post to Pinterest would link back to the original source, and include some sort of author/photographer attribution in the description. The original source would be the actual Q&A page for any questions or answers shared.

Pinterest is still figuring out how to make their Terms of Service work for them as a business without infringing on/changing licensing or rights to other people's content, and there is a huge range in attitudes about the value of Pinterest. Therefore, I'd love to hear any and all thoughts you guys have on the matter before I get started.

Comment: Pintrest seems like a great place to share G&L stuff. I'm in favour of it.

Comment: Cool. Since there haven't been any objections here, I'll include gardening content and get started soon! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes please.basically anything to get us both more traffic and more awesome questions!